# How to stop the while(true) in socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am using Java Socket programming. When I click button the first time, the Socket is working perfectly. But button and other functions are not working anymore. All are disabled or do not react when I click them.

This is Main Class

```
JButton btnRemote = new JButton("Remote ");
        btnRemote.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                ServerInitiator ser=new ServerInitiator();
                ser.initialize(4444);
            }
        });
```

Socket Class

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
        String port = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter listening port");
        new ServerInitiator().initialize(5555);
    }

    public void initialize(int port){

        try {
            ServerSocket sc = new ServerSocket(port);
            //Show Server GUI
            drawGUI();
           // drawGUI();
            //Listen to server port and accept clients connections
            while(true){
                Socket client = sc.accept();
                System.out.println("New client Connected to the server");
                //Per each client create a ClientHandler
                new ClientHandler(client,desktop);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Initialize should be done in a separate thread.

Comment: What is `ClientHandler` in above context? Can you share something about it?

Comment: Which "button other functions" do you mean?  It looks to me like the button has a single function, to spawn a `ServerInitiator`.

Comment: I was half way down the road when recognizing that it is `JButton` not `Button` and so not Android. Could you please add the tag for `Swing` or `AWT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate your GUI from your server logic. Anyway, 
you can make the *ClientHandler* a Runnable, then spawn a new Thread for each new client:

```
// server is listening
while (true){
...
new Thread(new ClientHandler(client, desktop)).start();
...
}
```